# Mandelbrot set incorrect picture

Tags: fractals

I'm writing an algorithm to generate the Mandelbrot set in Java. However, the final picture is incorrect. It looks like this

[image]

I was wondering if the algorithm was incorrect.

```
public void Mandlebrot() {
    float reMax=2;
    float imMax=2;
    float reMin=-2;
    float imMin=-2;
    float xDelta = (reMax - reMin)/test.width;
    float yDelta = (imMax - imMin)/test.height;

    int N=20000;
    float complex = imMin;
    for(int y=0; y<test.height; y++) {
        float real = reMin;
        for(int x=0; x<test.width; x++) {
            int count = 0;
            float complexC = 0.4f;
            float realC = 0.3f;

            while(count<N && complexC*complexC+realC*realC<=4.0f) {
                complexC = realC*realC-complexC*complexC + complex;
                realC = 2*complexC*realC + real;
                count++;
            }

            if(complexC*complexC+realC*realC<=4.0f) {
                setPixel(x,y) = 1000;
            } else {
                setPixel(x,y) = 1+ 1000*count/N;
            }

            real+=xDelta;
        }
        complex+=yDelta;
    }
}
```

Comment: A description of your algorithm in psuedocode would be more appropriate for this site.

Comment: It is called Mandelbrot, by the way. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set

Comment: I think you knowingly/unknowingly created java-applet tag. (it has zero tags, correct me if not). I think it is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @Edit: The [tag:java-applet] has six questions tagged (without counting this one).

Comment: Why do you initialise `complexC` and `realC` to $0.4$ and $0.3$ respectively? They should both be initialised to $0$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor ... or the code will in fact produce the Julia set for $0.4+0.3i$ instead of the Mandelbrot set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the loop

```
while(count<N && complexC*complexC+realC*realC<=4.0f) {
    complexC = realC*realC-complexC*complexC + complex;
    realC = 2*complexC*realC + real;
    count++;
}
```

You use the updated `complexC` to compute the new `realC`, but you ought to use the old one:

```
float oldC = complexC;
complexC = realC*realC-complexC*complexC + complex;
realC = 2*oldC*realC + real;
count++;
```

Besides, you seem to have flipped the real and imaginary parts. I think that only rotates the picture, though.